# Create a batch-file which executes a local saved (MY)SQL Text file

Tags: mysql

I want to create a batch-file which executes a local saved (MY)SQL Text file (sql procedure) The tables created by the execution of the sql-file will use data from a server I have access to (hostname: server1; Port: 3306, (my) username: User2 Password:I´m using no password so the password is empty, Connection Name: ConnectiontoSQLServer, Name of Schema: ABC ) 
->How will the command in the batch-file look like?

Thanks for your support!

I tried this now, but it´s not working:

```
mysql --host=server1 --port=3306 --user=User2 --password= --database=ABC < C:\Users\krohn\Documents\Arbeit\SQL Queries\Tabellen CRM-Work\Tabellenaktualisierung.sql
```

-> What´s wrong?

Comment: let´s say the path is C:\Users\X\Documents\\SQL Queries\ and the the name of the sql-procedure is XYZ.sql

Answer (score 1):

You can "execute" sql files on command line:

```
mysql -h server1 -u User2 < C:\Users\X\...
```

Comment: how can I see if it works?

Comment: Seems like it´s not working: nothing happens...

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If there is an error, than you will get that. If not, you have to check the database if your queries did execute.

Comment: I get no error and the querry is not executed

Comment: Anyone? Nothing happens: the window is opening and closing for about half a second and nothing happens in the schema

Comment: Can you confirm that it connects to the database by running it on the command line with a simple select query?

Comment: Can you write down such a SELECT command?

Comment: Without knowing your database structure? Only if you can tell me the name of my children?